# Which file structure would be most appropriate for codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Hello there I am having some thoughts on my file structure in codeigniter.What I'm doing right now is creating a folder with the project I'm developing for and name it let's say "myProject"
then I put my codeigiter folder inside that file.And then everything is done normally as by creating a class called myProject again on the controllers folder...

this structure works but it creates urls that are really ugly(for example in a local server):
http://localhost/myBlog/CodeIgniter_1.7.2/index.php/myBlog

also it creates some issues with my root folder...so if I have a css folder in my root I should call it like that:
"/myBlog/CodeIgniter_1.7.2/css/myBlogStyle.css"

and not like that:
"css/myBlogStyle.css"

do you have any suggestions on which is the right way to work with codeigniter?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your folder at the root level. Get rid of the CodeIgniter_1.7.2, you don't need that folder.

```
C:
  xampp (or whatever)
     www (or htdocs)
        myblog
           application
           system
           ...
```

For your css:

```
C:
  xampp (or whatever)
     www (or htdocs)
        myblog
           application
           system
           css (put your css scripts in a folder call css)
              default.css
```

Then to access it, just

`<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

To get rid of your "index.php" from your scripts, change/add a .htaccess file to the file like this. Just google a file of it and change the rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myblog/index.php?/$1 [L]

C:
  xampp (or whatever)
     www (or htdocs)
        myblog
           application
           system
           css (put your css scripts in a folder call css)
              default.css
           .htaccess
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...I tried removing the codeingiter folder and it worked for all the .css , .js and external files in general, but all my liks are still broken it seems that "CodeIgniter_1.7.2" is added to them no matter what..so for example a redirect to myBlog used to be redirect('myBlog/'); but now it doesn't work neither all the other links...any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: actually the links that don't work are those called by codeigniter methods..(in my case "anhors" and "redirects") another example of broken link: "anchor('myBlog/comments/'.$row->id, 'Comments/Post')"

Comment: Ok I fixed that I had to remove "CodeIgniter_1.7.2" from $config['base_url'] in the config/config.php file...